# recurrent loss of wireless connectivity

Tags: debian, wifi

My wireless connection is frequently terminated (reason unknown). I can remedy the problem either by rebooting or by unloading and reloading the kernel module for my wireless network interface controller (Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]).

The frequency with which the connection terminates appears to be random, so unloading and reloading the kernel once per minute (cron: `*/1 * * * * modprobe -r iwlagn; modprobe iwlagn; iwconfig`) usually provides uninterrupted connectivity for a period of a few hours.

If I recall correctly, this problem occurred shortly after upgrading to [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) support in Debian 7. Please advise if you know or can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a known issue with the N 1000 cards. I have one in my laptop that has been plagued by this issue since day one. What we ended up doing was disabling the N side of this card since that is where the issue was isolated by myself and others.

This blog post extensively covered the issue, titled:

- [Debugging an Intermittently Dropping Intel Wireless-N 1000 Network Card on Fedora 14](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6049/debugging-an-intermittently-dropping-intel-wireless-n-1000-network-card-on-fedora-14/)

You can disable wireless N functionality temporarily like so:

```
$ modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

To make it permanent:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/wireless.conf
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

then unload and reload the driver:

```
# unload
$ rmmod iwlagn

# load
$ modprobe iwlagn
```

#### Latest Intel Drivers

You can try downloading and installing the latest Centrino drivers for the N-1000 cards from here, [Wireless Networking + Intel® Wi-Fi Products  + Intel® Centrino® Wireless](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless%20Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%20Wi-Fi%20Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Centrino%C2%AE%20Wireless-N%201000).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try disabling 802.11N for a day or so to confirm that the network termination problem has resolved.

Comment: Implementing these steps seems to help somewhat, but the connection still terminates periodically, requiring manual reactivation using the commands specified in the original post.

Comment: @user001 - if you have control over the access point you might want to try disabling wireless-N there as well.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the access point is in a work environment, and I do not have control over it.

Comment: @user001 - if you're totally desperate you can try getting the latest Intel drivers, https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+Wi-Fi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Centrino%C2%AE+Wireless-N+1000. Added this to the answer too!