# my wifi Wireless-N 2230 can't connect occassionally

Tags: wifi

My wifi Wireless-N 2230 has quite often connection problems. My system is Fedora 18. Below are some logs from /var/log/messages. I can see that it changes "World regulatory domain" from PL to CZ and back all the time but not sure what that means.

```
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.028392] wlan0: disassociating from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.033850] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.034732] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046507] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046516] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046521] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046526] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046529] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046533] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046537] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.046577] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051348] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051354] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051359] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051363] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2301 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051366] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051370] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)                                                          
Nov  4 00:21:38 den kernel: [158784.051373] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)                                                      
Nov  4 00:21:39 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning                                                             
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.560724] wlan0: authenticate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.562341] wlan0: send auth to 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.564375] wlan0: authenticated
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.564826] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.564835] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.564840] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.564995] wlan0: associate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.567720] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.571052] wlan0: associated
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.571223] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575645] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575653] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575658] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575662] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575665] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575669] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den kernel: [158785.575673] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:39 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.577247] wlan0: disassociating from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.584453] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.585791] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591456] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591465] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591470] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591475] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591478] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591482] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591486] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.591517] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:49 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597174] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597177] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597178] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597180] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2301 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597181] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597182] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:49 den kernel: [158795.597183] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:50 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.086187] wlan0: authenticate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.090017] wlan0: send auth to 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.091987] wlan0: authenticated
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.092377] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.092390] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.092398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.093302] wlan0: associate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.096083] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.099180] wlan0: associated
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.099395] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:51 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106784] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106793] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106798] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106802] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106805] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106809] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:51 den kernel: [158797.106812] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.436347] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.440551] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446961] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446972] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446985] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446987] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446989] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446990] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.446992] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.447008] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451172] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CZ
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451176] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451178] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451180] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2301 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451182] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451184] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den kernel: [158798.451186] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Auto Ikarie' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Ikarie'
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Config: added 'proto' value 'WPA RSN'
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Nov  4 00:21:52 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.070448] wlan0: authenticate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.073906] wlan0: send auth to 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.075947] wlan0: authenticated
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.076258] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.076269] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.076276] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov  4 00:21:53 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.077217] wlan0: associate with 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (try 1/3)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.080030] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:01:38:fb:84:9d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.083331] wlan0: associated
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.083503] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088635] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: PL
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088643] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088648] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088652] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088656] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088659] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den kernel: [158799.088663] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
Nov  4 00:21:53 den NetworkManager[855]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
```

Comment: Regarding the regulatory domain, your computer seems to be confused about whether it's Poland or Czechoslovakia.  Couldn't say why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous question, titled: [recurrent loss of wireless connectivity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/recurrent-loss-of-wireless-connectivity/90689#90689). The N-1000 cards have continuously suffered from this issue. Generally there has been 3 options to get around it:

1. Disable Wireless-N on your WiFi access point
2. Disable Wireless-N in the WiFi client
3. Upgraded the firmware or drivers to resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you! It is not that often that it happens so ill go with removing/adding the wifi kernel module (they say it is iwlang, in my case it is iwldvm).