# How can I prevent my wifi driver from going catatonic?

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm using a Lenovo T430s with an `Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300` wireless chipset.  On certain wireless networks, I experience frequent wifi lockups, which require me to reload the wireless module thusly:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

The main clue, aside from lost connectivity, that I need to do this is that dmesg shows:

```
[ 9351.591170] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Queue 11 stuck for 2000 ms.
[ 9351.591178] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Current read_ptr 153 write_ptr 161
[ 9351.591182] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: On demand firmware reload
[ 9351.592001] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[ 9351.592149] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 9351.599072] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
```

1. What causes this?
2. Is there any way to prevent this?

I'm using Linux kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 from Debian wheezy.

Comment: It looks like a Hardware/Firmware/Driver failure. Hard to fix, even hard to workaround (except a script that looks for errors in logs and reloads the module). Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at my A to this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/recurrent-loss-of-wireless-connectivity/90689#90689. This sounds like a duplicate but will wait for you to try and confirm.

Comment: @slm: I'll try that.  I found another "solution" as well (`wd_disable=1`), although it seems less than ideal to disable the queue watchdog. Maybe the Wireless N disabling will be better.  I'll report back soon.

Comment: Please find a more common word to replace "catatonic" in the title - I see what you mean, but not preciese enough to replace it. Not sure how the medical condition applies...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two possible solutions. I'm not sure which one is "best".

Adding `wd_disable=1` to the module commandline seems to work, as does `11n_disable=1`, as suggested by @slm's answer linked in comments above.

In short, edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and add either:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

or

```
optoins iwlwifi wd_disable=1
```

FWIW, I'm using the former at the moment, as I know I don't want to use Wireless-N, and disabling a queue watchdog doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Using the 11n_disable line works for me too. This issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1615774 suggests that the problem might be related to USB3 devices. And actually I started having this problem once I plugged a USB3 disk into my notebook.

Comment: for me this means i connect at 802.11g speeds of 54mbps rather than 300+mbps 802.11ac speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I've just used the 11n_disable=1 on my Mint 19.3 install and it seems to have solved the issue I was having as well.

H/W
Dell Latitude E6400
Linux Mint 19.3 XFCE ( problem also showed up during live and installed Mint 20