# What driver should I use for my wireless card?

Tags: wifi, drivers, intel, thinkpad

I am wondering if my internal wireless adapter of T400 has the right driver `iwlwifi`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:26:c6:3e:30:34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-60-generic-pae firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn 
       resources: irq:48 memory:f4200000-f4201fff
```

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90689/674) slm said that [intel website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless%20Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%20Wi-Fi%20Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Centrino%C2%AE%20Wireless-N%201000) has the latest Centrino driver. I searched on intel website with "5100 AGN Shiloh", but doesn't found anything.  I wonder what word I should use for searching for my adapter?

Should either iwlwifi or intel official driver work well?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this kernel.org page on wireless drivers](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi/); yes you have the right driver! Whether or not a newer version (than what your distro supplies) would be better or not will depend... I have had newer versions of drivers work better but I have also had newer version work worse...

So the best answer to that question IMO is another question: "Does it work ok"?! I'm guessing from your link that perhaps not? But if the answer is yes, then IMO why mess with it!?

If you want to try a newer version, first thing I would do is check you distro. E.g. I use Debian so first I'd check for an updated firmware package in 'backports', next I'd check 'testing'. After that I'd have a look at kernel.org (link above) and/or check out backports.

AFAIK Intel only host drivers that haven't yet been integrated into the kernel. I doubt that they'd be still maintaining drivers for your card (so you'll need kernel.org for latest...).